# Getting cookies from the browser console

Tags: python, browser, python-requests, xss

There is a faculty member's host for a lab work on XSS vulnerability research. The first page is authorization, we do it manually. The second page has a text input field and a send button (but you can send text with Send button). If you enter the code `<script>console.log(document.cookie)</script>` in the text input field, you can see the user's cookies in the developer console.
I am creating a local server:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

Then I redirect user to the target page and call function for sending POST request:

```
url = 'http://targetsite'
payload = {
      'text': '<script>console.log(document.cookie)</script>',
}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

`text` is the name paramter from html code of the page.
And only the html code of the page is returned to me in response.
I have two questions:

1. Whether this response from the server is really correct even if I get `200 OK` code
2. Is there any way to send myself these `console.log(document.cookie)` in response?

Comment: There is some javascript running someplace on the page doing that. Probably using `eval()` demonstrating the dangers of trusting user input.